# Ошибка при отправки JSON на cервер методом POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Через `ajax` отправляю **POST** запрос на сервер в формате `JSON`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот javascript код:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После, сервер принимает `$_POST` данные и с помощью функции `json_decode()` декодирует в `JSON` формат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но в итоге выдает ошибку:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще при команде `print_r($_POST)` сервер выдает пустой массив.

**В чем же ошибка?**

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `dataType: "json"`. И попробуйте в `data` просто передать `obj`.

Comment: @entithat Не получается

Comment: Раз при `print_r($_POST)` ничего не выводиться, значит проблемы с ajax запросом. Попробуйте добавить `.error: function(data) {}` и посмотреть что выведет.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё без `contentType`.

Comment: Попробуйте вывести через `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то будьте добры, нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом и на треугольник вверх. Спасибо.

Comment: @Diskyp -  Если я не сделал этого, то значит ваш вопрос не помог мне решить мою проблему. "треугольник вверх" я поставлю вам за попытку решить ее. Спасибо

Comment: @ruslan4742 да приходится совершать обход, вставляя эту копипасту, ибо многие люди просто забывают отметить моё решение. И кстати мой ответ абсолютно справедлив и отвечает на ваши вопросы. Это подтверждается и тем, что его не заминусили, не опровергли и не написали другого, приняв мою правоту. Если у вас остались какие-то вопросы или недопонимания, я всегда открыт обсудить их в комментариях к ответу и дополнить своё решение, не стесняйтесь общения с людьми, что отозвались на вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2):

JS

```
let data=JSON.stringify({name:'Celestia',age:2385,city:'Canterlot'})
$.ajax({
  url:'ponyville/student/twilightSparkle.nerd',
  type:'POST',
  contentType:'application/JSON',
  data:{data},
  success:data=>alert('Equestria was saved again!')
})
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST)) var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));
```

Вы пытались декодировать суперглобальный массив, на что получали справедливую ошибку. Пуст он был от того, что с клиента нужно отправлять данные в виде объекта, которые затем, по одноимённому ключу, можно получить на сервере из `$_POST` массива.